# Cypress.io - geoLocation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

i'm testing a react based software with Cypress.io and there are dynamic language outputs happening.

Is there any way to simulate the users geolocation and language with cypress?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use VPN (*windscribe* in Linux).

So i installed and started *windscribe* and connect to different locations (US, London, Paris)

```
windscribe connect US
```

You have 10 Gb / month free.

I switch location to France (*windscribe connect FR*) and repeat the tests.

In Windows you have TunnelBear witch give you 500Mb/month. I used it also.